# mysql/jdbc function in out param

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

So i need to run a jdbc call that is going against a sql server database.

```
CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{ ? = call " + spName + " ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) }");
```

So the sql server call is a function that has output parameters.

we are using mysql database and it looks like mysql functions don't support functions with out put parameters.  i tried to see if i could fake out the call using store procs with output parameters but no luck.

any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're right. mysql doesn't support output parameters on functions, only stored procedures. you'll have to rewrite the function so it only has one return value, or as a procedure where you've moved the return value to an out variable.